# selecting a particular subset of data when clicking on a button in spotfire

Tags: button, filter, spotfire

I am new to Spotfire and was wondering how I should create a button in a dashboard that returns the number of Groupings where Val > 100.00. Then, once I click on that button, the corresponding data should be filtered.

Below is an extract of the dataset:

```
Grouping    Part_Num     Month    Val
CF1         129077       M1       3000.00
CF1         129078       M1       409.00
CF1         129080       M1       4568.00
CF2         123898       M1       980.00
CF2         1348976      M1       0.00
CF2         1128799      M1       8878.00
```

Comment: Do you need help with the button creation or where to apply the logic of the action?

Answer (score 1):

@Galileo- Instead of a button, you can try using either drop down or a slider to dynamically control  the values filtered.

- Add text area and insert property control (drop down list/slider) as per your choice
- Create a new property control, give it a name and assign values (fixed/range/from column)
- Right click on the table (where values are filtered based on the selection from property control) and go to **Data > Limit data using expression** and add the below line in that section (the below expression is for slider).

  [Val]>DocumentProperty("SelectRange")

[image]

Now, the property control is linked to your table. Whenever you select a value from the slider, table values are filtered.

***Screenshot of the final output:***

[image]

Hope this helps!